# Emptying trash, with file-in-use: Is there any difference between 'skip' and 'continue'?

Tags: macos, finder, trash

If you delete a file, but it's still in use (e.g. a document still open), and then try to empty the trash you get something like this:

[image: Emptying trash, file in use dialog]

As best I can tell the three options do the following:

- **Skip**: ignore this file and keep trashing the rest
- **Stop**: stop trashing files
- **Continue**: ignore this file and keep trashing the rest

As far as I can tell, **Skip** and **Continue** do exactly the same thing. I've tested this by deleting a few files, and using either option they seem to trash all the other files.

But it seems weird that Apple would supply two buttons which do exactly the same thing.

So does anyone know of any technical difference in the behaviours of the **Skip** vs **Continue** buttons?

*I'm using 10.10.3 Yosemite, but I believe the options have been like this for a few major versions*.

Comment: As an aside, I find the presence of any options to be a bit silly. I can't really imagine using **Stop**, because its only protecting *some* of the not-in-use files (any already trashed before this one got caught 'in use' are gone), and you've *already* confirmed you want to trash everything. So of the 3 options, 2 seem to be identical, and the other pointlessly confusing. I think it should auto-continue and just show an error that some files couldn't be trashed.

Comment: That is very odd...

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find any documented proof but still, here is my answer.

When you first hit above shown error, it means you can

- **Skip** i.e. don't try to trash mentioned file and continue trashing the rest
- **Stop** i.e. stop trashing for now
- **Continue** i.e. **you have closed mentioned file (*it's not in use anymore*) and OSX can continue trashing it**

If you just click continue or fail to close the open file, OSX skips them and hence the confusion.

*Most of the in-use files I have seen are plists which needs to be unloaded before deleting*

### Extra info after some experiment:

*Above said is mostly true in situations when trash contains plists or in general you trashed some ap*p

**For example:**

If you create a text file → Open it → Trash it while the file is still open → Try empty Trash → No problem ***i.e. Trash empty without any error and file still open***

But If  you start some app (*like MAMP in my experiment*) → Launch it & start services → Trash the app → Try empty trash → You will get the above said error → Open activity monitor → Kill all related services & hit continue → Trash empty

[image]

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. I ran `cat > testfile` from the command line, deleted the testfile, emptied the trash (it complained as above), killed the `cat` command and then hit continue, but the testfile was not trashed.

Comment: At times it won't even complain even the when the file is open. Running 10.11.3 and just tried what you did and no complains, file is still open and trash is empty. What I said above is the most logical thing I could come up with as I have explained, I don't have any documented proof for this

Comment: @drfrogsplat I've more info after some experiment, hope it answers your question/doubt

Answer (score 0):

I got confirmation today from a Sr. Rep that your suspicion is correct on the Skip, Stop, Continue meanings. Continue is the same as skip, but it's giving you an option: temporary time to close out the problematic file and essentially "try again" before moving on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/339450)

Comment: It absolutely, 100% answers the question, and definitively. It came right from an Apple Sr. Advisor and not just the Internet. That's as solid an answer you can get. Just because I didn't reiterate the entire question from the top and babyfeed back to you what you just read doesn't mean it's any less an answer. And it makes sense, if you think about it. That explains why Skip and Continue do seemingly the same thing, at first. This 100% clears everything up.